# How to deserialize dictionary types to json in dotnet core

Tags: c#, .net-core, sendgrid, dotnet-httpclient, json-deserialization

I am working on some integrations with SendGrid's APIs, particularly around the search functionality in emails.

The API response is like so:

```json
{
   "result":{
      "personsemail@domain.com":{
         "contact":{
            "address_line_1":"",
            "address_line_2":"",
            "alternate_emails":[
               
            ],
            "city":"",
            "country":"",
            "email":"personsemail@domain.com",
            "first_name":"Bob",
            "id":"111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111",
            ...
         }
      },
      "anotheremail@domain.com":{
         "contact":{
            "address_line_1":"",
            "address_line_2":"",
            "alternate_emails":[
               
            ],
            "city":"",
            "country":"",
            "email":"anotheremail@domain.com",
            "first_name":"Alice",
            "id":"111112-1112-1112-1112-111111111112",
            ...
         }
      }
      ...
   }
}
```

Does anyone know how I can deserialize this appropriately so I can use it like a normal list to iterate/search with? I'm hoping I can use something like this:

```cs
var recipients = (await searchResponse.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<**my-poco**>());
```

Which is similar to what I'm using for all the other calls - but I'm not sure how to create the POCO that will allow for a simple deserialization. I'm happy to ignore the top level personsemail@domain.com entry and just search through the results with linq..

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you looking for solution with System.Text.Json or with Json.NET?

Comment: Did you try to deserialize it into Dictionary<string, Contact>?

Comment: Either JSON deserialization solution will work with me.. as long as it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up getting this working with the following class. This is a variation to Peter's answer:

```
public class SendGridContactSearchResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("result", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    //public Result Result { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Contact> result { get; set; }
}

public partial class Contact
{
    [JsonProperty("contact", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public contact contact { get; set; }
}

public partial class contact
{
    [JsonProperty("address_line_1", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("address_line_2", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("alternate_emails", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public List<object> AlternateEmails { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("city", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string City { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("country", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Country { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("email", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("first_name", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("id", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public Guid? Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("last_name", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("list_ids", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public List<object> ListIds { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("segment_ids", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public List<object> SegmentIds { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("postal_code", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("state_province_region", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string StateProvinceRegion { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("phone_number", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("whatsapp", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Whatsapp { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("line", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Line { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("facebook", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string Facebook { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("unique_name", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string UniqueName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("custom_fields", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public CustomFields CustomFields { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("created_at", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public DateTimeOffset? CreatedAt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("updated_at", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public DateTimeOffset? UpdatedAt { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("_metadata", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public Metadata Metadata { get; set; }
}
```

The fix was in the SendGridContactSearchResponse class referencing a Contact class in the dictionary. The invocation was this:

```
var searchResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SendGridContactSearchResponse>(json);
```

and the deserialization worked fine!

Answer (score 1):

One way is to paste the api response as class using visual studio. You can click on `Edit -> Paste special -> Paste JSON as Classes`.
Doing this you will have these classes:

```
public class EmailModel
{
    public Result result { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public PersonsemailDomainCom personsemaildomaincom { get; set; }
}

public class PersonsemailDomainCom
{
    public Contact contact { get; set; }
}

public class Contact
{
    public string address_line_1 { get; set; }
    public string address_line_2 { get; set; }
    public object[] alternate_emails { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
    public string country { get; set; }
    public string email { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am aware of this feature, but unfortunately this approach won't work because the API will return more than one result. And personsemaildomaincom will always be a different email address. I have edited the question to show what the API response looks like when there is more than one Contact found.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Contact
    {
        public Contact2 contact { get; set; }
    }

    public class Contact2
    {
        public string city { get; set; } ..other props
    }

string a = @"{
            ""personsemail @domain.com"":{
                ""contact"":{
                    ""city"":""""
                    }
            },
        ""personsemail @domain.com2"":{
                ""contact"":{
                    ""city"":""""
                }
            }
        }";

            var ddd = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Contact>>(a);
```

Comment: The JSON payload is different to what you are setting in string a - the root element is: result

Answer (score 0):

You can map your json to the following data model:

```
public class Response
{
    public Dictionary<string, Contact> Results { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Contact
{
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public List<string> AlternateEmails { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

Depending on the Serialization library of your choice (System.Text.Json or Json.NET) you should annotate the properties with either [`JsonPropertyNameAttribute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonpropertynameattribute?view=net-6.0) or [`JsonPropertyAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/jsonpropertyname.htm)

Then you can call the `ReadFromJsonAsync` with a `Response` type parameter.

---

Since the e-mail addresses are stored in a redundant fashion you should be able to convert your `Dictionary<string, Contact>` to a `List<Contact>` collection

```
public class Response
{
    public Dictionary<string, Contact> Results { get; set; }
    public List<Contact> Contacts => Results.Values.ToList();
}
```